# Modifying the jm spinner dot to make it same size without the bounce

Tags: html, css

I'm using the [jm spinner](https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Ajax-Loader-jQuery-CSS3-jmspinner.html) plugin on my site, but I want to change the bouncing dots from changing size (bouncing) when they show. They display as a 'bounce' that makes them look like they are growing in size. I just want them to stay the same size, but I've been playing with the .css file and the debugger and I can't figure out to make any changes!

Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/nmptk/pen/vLxqQj)

On the site it says I can modify/style the spinner like

```
.spinner {
 }
```

but I'm not sure what to put here.

It seems like I don't want the 'sk-bouncedelay' but not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? If so, you can forget about the plugin.

```css
.spinner>div {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showhide 1.4s infinite;
}

.spinner .dot1 {
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.spinner .dot2 {
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

@keyframes showhide {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="dot1"></div>
  <div class="dot2"></div>
  <div class="dot3"></div>
</div>
```